# How to split an array after that to update it and make a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
$test = $_POST['test'];

print_r($test); 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26629
            [timestamp] => 1332273712
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26628
            [timestamp] => 1332243526
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26627
            [timestamp] => 1332237777


)
```

I want to get timestamp value and using a funciton to change it to something like 5 sec ago,4 hours ago and so on. The function is the easy part i'm just goin to use time() - timestamp..

Then when i get the new value have to make a new array with them that is going to content something like that

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26629
            [content] => 5 sec ago
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26628
            [content] => 4 hours ago
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26627
            [content] => 1 hour ago


)
```

Probably i have to use foreach but i dont know how :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive().](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Your could could look like this:

```
//Make a copy of the array first, then operate on it, so that the final result is a seperate array.
$final = $test;

function transformTime(&$item, $key){

    if($key == "timestamp"){
        //Do something to $item
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($final, 'transformTime');

//Convert to JSON for XHR:
$result = json_encode($final);
```

Code I am testing with:

```
<?php

$test = array(

        array('id' => 26629, 
        'timestamp' => 1332273712),

        array('id' => 26628, 
        'timestamp' => 1332243526),

        array('id' => 26629,
        'timestamp' => 1332273712),

        array('id' => 26629,
        'timestamp' => 1332273712),
);

var_dump($test);

$final = $test;

function transformTime(&$item, $key){

    if($key == "timestamp"){
        $item = $item + 5; //Obviously you need to convert the timestamp to something friendly here.
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($final, 'transformTime');

var_dump($final);
```

Comment: 2.6629266282666273e+24 No Properties

Comment: The edited version show the same error 2.6629266282666273e+24 No Properties

Comment: No idea why you are getting that. Just tested the code, it it was able to update the timestamp properly. I didn't get it to convert the time stamp, but it was able to udpate the value.

Comment: Are you receiving this using AJAX? If so, you need to `json_encode()` the array.

Comment: hmm ok now what is changing is the id. id = 5 ; and if echo $item before f($key == "id"){} i get the id and timestamp not only the timestamp

Comment: So if you wanted to change the timestamp, check for "timestamp" in the key as per the updated code.

Comment: :D Yes I get it finally thanks alot @phpdev. But how to make it use cyrillic because if i use $item = $num.' ago'; is ok but if i use $item = $num.' преди'; is a mess

Comment: Are you sending the response as utf-8? You need to send the response as utf-8 or the appropriate character set so that the browser knows how to decode it.

Comment: I try JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE but i cant use it since my php is below 5.4.Then i try some replacements form php.net but the last item is mess

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. Before echoing your JSON content, just do: `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: It dosent work [{"id":"26630","timestamp":"\u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0438 5 \u0441\u0435\u043a"},]

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    $test[$key]['content'] = get_timeago($value['timestamp']);
}
```

Copy `get_timeago` function from [Here](http://tutorialfeed.net/development/timeago-style-php-timestamps).

Comment: 1.3322737121332243e+49 No Properties

Comment: what's that ? can you explain

Comment: In the google chrome debugging tool in XHR section i get this Preview

Comment: Yes to make sure it work i make this function get_timeago($ptime){

echo $ptime;
} and the result is 1.3322737121332243e+49 No Properties

Comment: Copy that function from "http://tutorialfeed.net/development/timeago-style-php-timestamps", you don't need to write your own function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Handling array

$arr = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            'id' => 26629,
            'content' => '5 sec ago',
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            'id' => 26628,
            'content' => '4 hours ago',
        ),

    2 => array
        (
            'id' => 26627,
            'content' => '1 hour ago',
        )

);

 foreach($arr as $arr1)
 {
    foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo $val.'<br />';
    }

}

 Find ago time pass time to it

function agoWord( $value )
  {
    if(isset ($value))
    {

      if(time() < strtotime($value))
      {
        $agoWord = "away";
      }
      else
      {
        $agoWord = "ago";
      }
      return $agoWord;
    }
    else
    {
      return 'Time not set for display.';
    }
  }

Function to calculate time differnce

function timeDiff($value)
  {
    if(isset ($value))
    {
      $ago = abs(time() - strtotime($value));

      if($ago < 60)
      {
          $span = $ago;
          return ($span != 1) ? $span." seconds" : " a second";
      }
      if($ago < 3600)
      {
          $span = round($ago/60);
          return ($span != 1) ? $span." minute" : " one minute";
      }
      if($ago < 86400)
      {
          $span = round($ago/3600);
          return ($span != 1) ? $span." hours" : " one hours";
      }

      if($ago < 2592000) // 86400*30 (Month)
      {
          $span = round($ago/86400);
          return ($span != 1) ? $span." days" : " one day";
      }

      if($ago < 31536000) // 86400*365 (time<Year)
      {
          $span = round($ago/2592000);
          return ($span != 1) ? $span." months" : " one month";
      }

      if($ago >= 31536000) //86400*365 (time>=Year)
      {
          $span = round($ago/31536000);
          return ($span != 1) ? $span." years" : " one year";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return 'error';
    }
  }
```